# How do I mass move apps to SD card?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, nokia-lumia-730

Since I updated my Lumia 730 to Windows 10 I see some apps moved back to the phone memory. I'd really like to move all apps (that can be moved) to the SD card.

This was easy in WP 8.1:

[image: Mass selecting apps in WP8.1]

but I can't find a way in Windows 10 Mobile. Tap and hold only shows the app developer.

Answer (score 4):

In the settings app you can click the *System* submenu. Under *Storage* you can move apps from the phone to a SD card by tapping the app and chossing *move*. As far as I have seen there is not a possibility to move all apps possible at the same time. If you however sort by size you can move the largest ones first to clean up the most space.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, yeah kind of. But that's the problem, I'd have to do it one by one. There are too many, plus some cannot be moved but I must tap to know that.

Comment: I am awfully sorry but it also annoys me. There's still no choice 